# Error connecting Staubli CS8 robot to ROS

Tags: ros, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there !

I have a robot Staubli tx60 and I want to connect it with ROS, I have a package for that but it doesn't work:
I get this message:

```
[ERROR] [1423580378.785944834]: Failed to connect to Staubli CS8 Controller.
```

[image: image description]

This message comes from the package not from ROS.

in the other side I have my CS8 emulator in other machine in windows7:

[image: image description]

The objectif is to connect CS8 Emulator that has an IP address with ROS using a package

Anyone worked with CS8 emulator in ROS ?

[This](https://www.mediafire.com/?lgwx76kp5mjmm8k) is the package that I use.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202941/error-connecting-staubli-cs8-robot-to-ros/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2015-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-12**:
There is probably more output on the console than just this single error? Could you update your post with some more context as well?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-02-12**:
@gvdhoorn I just edit my question and add more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did some modification in main function:

instead of:

```
if ( argc<2 || (strstr(argv[1],"http://")!=argv[1]) || !strstr(argv[1],":800/") )
```

I use

```
if ( argc<2 || (strstr(argv[1],"http://")!=argv[1]) )
```

And it works !

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-12**:
Yes that first line doesn't really make sense. Nice to hear that it works now. You should accept your own answer, to mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you correctly configured the IP address for the staubli node to connect to (in `controller.h`)?

According to your screenshot, the node is trying to connect to 10.1.22.254, but your CS8 emulator shows its using 10.1.22.64? I'm not 100% sure the simulator reports the IP of the pc it's running on, but in any case you should check that the ROS node is using the correct address.

---

Edit: check firewall settings on the Windows machine. It might be that the emulator is only allowed to accept traffic on *private* or *public* networks. Disabling it would give a quick way to test this (but please do return it to a working state afterwards).

---

Edit2:

Looking at the source in the archive you linked, two things stand out:

```
 ROS_INFO("* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *");
 ROS_INFO("* MAKE SURE CS8 CONTROLLER IS IN NETWORKED MODE *");
 ROS_INFO("* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *");
```

And:

```
if(staubli.Login( url, "default", ""))
{
    ROS_INFO("Connected to Staubli CS8 Controller.");
}
else
{
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to connect to Staubli CS8 Controller.");
}
```

So:

1. Is the controller in *Networked Mode*
2. I'm guessing the `Login(..)` method uses some sort of username/password combination. Has that info been changed on the controller perhaps? Is the password for *default* still "" (an empty string)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-02-12**:
Sorry I uploaded the wrong photo, Now it's OK !

I'm not using the package that has (controller.h) because I got lot of errors when I compile it, I use another one that you can download it, up there in the end of my question.

The PC and CS8 have the same address: 10.1.22.64 and ROS has 10.1.16.15

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-12**:
If you don't use the cu-ros-pkg, why do you link to the PDF?

Also: have you checked your firewall settings?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-02-12**:
My firewall is deactivated in both side in Ubuntu and Windows 7.

The PDF explains what I want exactly, but I can delete it if my question is clear enough

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-12**:
Does `nc 10.1.22.64 800` work? Or do you get a connection refused error?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-02-12**:
no, it doesn't BUT I did some modification in main function:
instead of:

```
if ( argc<2 || (strstr(argv[1],"http://")!=argv[1]) || !strstr(argv[1],":800/") )
```

I use

```
if ( argc<2 || (strstr(argv[1],"http://")!=argv[1]) )
```

I get
[ INFO] [14230559.064007445]: Connected to Staubli CS8 Controller.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-02-12**:
I don't know how it will influence the package working !
do you know what !strstr(argv[1],":800/") exactly means in the program !?

*Yes the controller in Networked Mode
*for the login/password I don't really have any login or password !

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-12**:\

> no, it doesn't

If netcat can't connect to port 800 on your Windows machine, then I think that is something you should check.

Also: please update your original question with any new information. The comments don't allow for too much discussion and / or copy/pasting console text.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-02-12**:
then I have to look for the port in my windows machine ?